# Quick switching between language keyboards

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, language

How can I switch quickly back and forth between the English keyboard and the German keyboard on macOS?

Comment: Mac, iPad, iPhone? Also which version of the OS is on your device.

Comment: I don't see any globe icon. Where is it??

Comment: I am at system pref -> keyboard -> input sources, and "show input menu in menu bar" is ticked, but there is no icon in the upper right. Just a search box.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS, tap(or hold) the globe key.

In macOS, try <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>space bar</kbd>. Press and  hold control and then press space to get a list of languages.

If menu bar has input sources shortcut enabled in keyboard settings, one can use it too.

Comment: Thank you, but pressing and holding "control" and then pressing the space bar does not do anything.

Comment: I watched a youtube instruction and ticked both boxes in Keyboard > Shortcuts, and now "control + slace bar"  changes the keyboards. But is there is anywhere on the screen an indication of which language keyboard is active? Or do I just have to experiment by typing something?

Comment: @PeterSchultz In MacOS the active keyboard is normally indicated by a "flag" icon in the top right corner of the screen.

Comment: I see it now. Problem solved. Thank you very much.